# Access List<Object> in subclasses

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, access-modifiers

I am writing a Simulation for traffic at the moment. I'm working on the class for items (cross roads) that can be placed on the gui.

One method use a List and simply adds groups of traffic lights (synchronized traffic lights) to the list List tlg using the constructor.

```
public TrafficLightGroup(int tlgID, Direction? direction, Lane lane1, Lane? lane2)
    {
        this.tlgID = tlgID;
        this.lane1 = lane1;
        this.lane2 = lane2;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

class Item
{
public virtual void SetTrafficLightSystem()
    {
        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(1, Direction.West, Lane.Left, Lane.Straight));
        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(2, Direction.West, Lane.Right, null));

        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(3, Direction.South, Lane.Left, Lane.Straight));
        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(4, Direction.South, Lane.Right, null));

        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(1, Direction.East, Lane.Left, Lane.Straight));
        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(2, Direction.East, Lane.Right, null));

        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(3, Direction.North, Lane.Left, Lane.Straight));
        tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(4, Direction.North, Lane.Right, null));


    }
}
```

Now I want to access the same list from a subclass called CrossingPedestrians and change the base method. How do I access the List? I used defaul get; and set; for now but I read that this wont be the a good solution.

Here the subclass

```
class CrossingPedestrians : Item
{
    public override void SetTrafficLightSystem()
    {
        base.SetTrafficLightSystem();                       
        Tlg.Add(new TrafficLightGroup(5, null, Lane.Pedestrian, null));
    }
```

So, how can I solve the problem about accessing the list properly since the accessors, which I don't think will function the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should show us the relevant part of the `Item` class.**

Anyway, you are probably worried about exposing `Tlg` as a property. That is not wrong by itself, you only have to make it `protected`:

```
protected List<TrafficLightGroup> Tlg {get; set;}
```

This way child classes still can access it, but the outside world can't.